# Bootstrap js screen size incongruence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a footer that shows up as a collapsed accordion on mobile, while on desktop the accordion shows as expanded with all list items. It works fine with the js I am using.

However, as I am *expanding* my viewport from mobile size to desktop size, the accordion will still stay collapsed. Conversely, when I make the screen *smaller*, the accordion shows expanded like it did on desktop.

I need the js to behave differently with screen size, as it's happening, dynamically, not just after I refresh. If I refresh, of course it looks fine.

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/us0x1IHkOU) with my footer.

Comment: Your example works perfectly. Maybe you have to clear your cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code to show panels on screens wider than 768px during resizing the browser (you can use `else` statement to hide them on smaller sizes).

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  if($(this).width() > 768) {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
  } else {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
  }
});

$(window).trigger('resize');

$('.footer-panels [data-toggle=collapse]').click(function(e) {
  if($(window).width() > 768) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }    
});
```

Plus/minus buttons CSS:

```
.footer-panels [data-toggle=collapse] span:before {
  content: '\f068';
}
.footer-panels [data-toggle=collapse].collapsed span:before {
  content: '\f067';
}
```

### [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/eg402ZRwKQ)

Comment: This works perfectly for mobile to desktop. But what about from desktop to mobile (i.e. shrinking the screen).

Comment: What do you want to achieve from desktop to mobile? I edited the post. You can check it

Comment: Beautiful! That's exaxctly what I wanted. Thank you for understanding my hard-to-formulate question :)

Comment: Also I improved your `plus/minus` buttons to behave correctly. You don't need JavaScript for that.

Comment: Thanks for that! I like how it's much neater now.

Comment: While I have you here, would you know how to disable the heading link (contact, hours, policies) on desktop? I don't need them to be collapsible at all.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Just noticed this code is causing the accordion panels to all stay open even when clicking a different panel. I need them to close when I click a different one. Plus it's affecting all my accordions on the site.